# Is it possible to access the protected methods outside the class - ruby

Tags: ruby

```
class User    
  def say_secret_with_self
    self.secret
  end

  protected

  def secret
    "secret"
  end
end

u = User.new
p u.say_secret_with_self   # => "secret"
```

I have heard that protected methods can be accessed only by inherited members. But the above is possible in ruby. Is it correct code?

Comment: `self.secret` can be simplified to `secret` as `self` is the implicit receiver. If, however `secret` were `private` one cannot use an explicit receiver, even `self`; you must write just `secret`.

Comment: What is “inherited members” supposed to mean? Also, if it is possible, it’s a correct code.

Comment: _"Is it possible to access the protected methods outside the class"_ – you don't access the _protected_ method `secret` from outside the class. You access the _public_ method `say_secret_with_self`. The protected method is called from _within_ the class.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is correct code. An instance of the class is able to call self methods even if they are `protected`. `protected/private` methods are hidden from the outside but not from inside.

Answer (score 2):

the method `secret` is still protected. you cant call it from outside of your class (or inherited class). but you can call it from `say_secret_with_self` because it is still in the same class with `secret`